# Electrode/solution interface : What's the difference between the electrochemical Peltier heat and the heat caused from the overpotential?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, heat

In principle heat effects caused by the passage of an electric current might arise from: electronic peltier effect at the junction of electrode/solution level, Joule effect due to solution resistance, electrochemical Petier effect at the interface level and the thermal effect due overpotential. What is the difference between the last two ones?